# AutoFac + ReactiveUI ViewFor<IViewModelType> Registration

Tags: c#, autofac, reactiveui

I'm new to AutoFac (and ReactiveUI!) and I'm having an issue registering a View with the container.

The View has the signature:

```
public partial class DataSelectView : IViewFor<IDataSelectViewModel>
```

I have the following registrations with the container already set up:

```
builder.RegisterType<DataSelectView>().As<IViewFor<IDataSelectViewModel>>();
builder.RegisterType<DataSelectViewModel>().As<IDataSelectViewModel>();
```

When I run the program I find that AutoFac is trying to resolve `IViewFor<DataSelectViewModel>` rather than `IViewFor<IDataSelectViewModel>` and therefore throws an error saying it can't find `IViewFor<DataSelectViewModel>.`

I don't want to change the View declaration to `: IViewFor<DataSelectViewModel>` as I want to maintain the flexibility to change the registration of `IDataSelectViewModel` to some other default implementation in the future when necessary.

I feel like I'm making an easy mistake here but can't work out how to resolve it! Any help much appreciated.

Comment: If you don't want to change the declaration, why not change the registration. Instead of builder.RegisterType<DataSelectView>().As<IViewFor<IDataSelectViewModel>>(); use builder.RegisterType<DataSelectView>().As<IViewFor<DataSelectViewModel>>();

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that originally but I get another error saying that `DataSelectView` is not assignable to `IViewFor<DataSelectViewModel>`. It seems that the Splat service locator that ReactiveUI uses by default is happy with that kind of registration but AutoFac won't accept it.

Comment: @Nihilus Except if you convert your interface as a contravariant interface (see update on my answer)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to change your `DataSelectView` to allow generic :

```
public class DataSelectView<TViewModel> : IViewFor<TViewModel>
    where TViewModel : IViewModel
```

Then register it using the `RegisterGeneric` method :

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(DataSelectView<>)).As(typeof(IViewFor<>));
```

Autofac will then be able to resolve `IViewFor<DataSelectViewModel>`

---

Another possible solution would be to make the `IViewFor<T>` interface contravariant, using the *in* keyword on generic declaration. *Autofac* will then be able to resolve `IViewFor<DataSelectViewModel>`.

```
// Add the in modifier
public interface IViewFor<in TViewModel>
    where TViewModel : IDataSelectViewModel
{ }

// register it this way
builder.RegisterType<DataSelectView>().As<IViewFor<DataSelectViewModel>>();

// resolve works with 
container.Resolve<IViewFor<DataSelectViewModel>>();
```

By converting your interface to a contravariant interface you won't be able to return object of type `TViewModel` in your `IViewFor<>` interface

```
public interface IViewFor<in TViewModel>
    where TViewModel : IDataSelectViewModel
{ 

    void Do(TViewModel vm); // allowed
    TViewModel Do(); // disallowed
}
```

You can find more information here : [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can see that your approach would work but the problem is DataSelectView is a WPF UserControl with a separate XAML definition (declared as `partial` in my snippet above). I've seen that it is possible to create generic WPF controls but this seems like a very long workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to customize how View Location works, you can override it entirely:

```
ViewLocator.Current = new MyCoolViewLocator();
```

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/238524a922aed50f8141a1d26ff24b8f2b101b60/ReactiveUI/RegisterableInterfaces.cs#L323